# Batch file which saves user input path with spaces to a text file. (win 7)

Tags: input, batch-file

First of all i am a noob in programming.
I am trying to make a batch file which takes an installed directory of a program as user input when run for the first time (means it should not ask for the directory the second time it is run). By searching for various scripts, i reached till here,

```
 @echo off
Echo =============================================

echo Directory

Echo =============================================

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set /p mypath=Please specify install directory; 

Echo %mypath% ----was what you typed

pause

echo start>temp.txt

echo %mypath%>>temp.txt

echo \programfolder\program.exe>>temp.txt

echo -argument -argument>>temp.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set FINAL=

for /f %%a in (temp.txt) do (

set FINAL=!FINAL!%%a

)

echo %FINAL%>input.txt

del /q temp.txt

Pause

start "<input.txt"
```

This saves the input path in the "input.txt" text file, and runs the program the next time it is launched.
I want the text file to have the saved path as "start driveletter:\foldername\foldername with spaces\programfolder\program.exe" -arguments
However the "start", "program folder", "program.exe" and "-arguments" are fixed.
The user input path should get saved in- %mypath%.

Comment: please provide an example of what you expected and of what you got instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The does what you asked, I think:

```
@echo off
if exist "go.bat" go.bat
set /p "mypath=Please specify install directory; "
Echo "%mypath%" ----was what you typed
pause
>"go.bat" echo @start "" "%mypath%\programfolder\program.exe" -argument -argument
```

Comment: Well thank you very much for your reply, it works but go.bat do not go to the saved directory instead it tries to start the program.exe in the current directory, Help

Comment: Where is the saved directory?